# php find column name

Tags: php, arrays

I am having trouble isolating the "pdf icon" from the following array:
The links to the file work, but the have a  class refering to the pdf that is not being rendered.
I want to get rid of the Array(12) { [0] => String ( etc..)

```
$pdf_links  = array();
    
for($i=1; $i<=12; $i++){
    
    $pdf_file  = "/pub/pdf/" . $year . sprintf("%02d", $i) . "file.pdf";
            
    if (file_exists($document_root . $pdf_file)){
        $pdf_links[] = '<a class="pdf" lang="en" href="' . $pdf_file . '" target="_blank">' . date("M", mktime(0, 0, 0, $i, 24, $year)) . '</a>';
    }
    
}

if(count($pdf_links) >=1 ){
        echo "<dt>$year</dt>";
  echo "<dd><div class=\"floatleft\">" .implode(' ', $pdf_links). "</div></dd>";


}
  var_dump($pdf_links);
```

[image]

Please let me know if you need more information. Thanks!

Comment: do `print_r($pdf_links);` for arrays.

Comment: `I want to get rid of the Array(12) { [0] => String ( etc..)` You mean remove the last element from the array? OR element with key as 12 ?

Comment: @KUMAR I just want to echo the HTML inside the array

Comment: @Aashishgaba As you can see from the picture, I just want the PDF icons and the link and Months

Comment: The picture that you added it's the output from var_dump() or from this `echo "<dd><div class=\"floatleft\">" .implode(' ', $pdf_links). "</div></dd>";
` ? I believe it's from var_dump().

Comment: @Aashishgaba The picture is being returned by the var_dump, but I wanted to echo it though

Comment: Then just loop over the array, and echo the pdf_link. It's getting a little confusing, so why don't you paste the current output, and the expected output. Also, mention in the question what piece of code is getting that output.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218965/discussion-between-aashish-gaba-and-staminna).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `var_dump` for printing.

The code block that you already have would do the job.

```
if(count($pdf_links) >=1 ){
        echo "<dt>$year</dt>";
  echo "<dd><div class=\"floatleft\">" .implode(' ', $pdf_links). "</div></dd>";
}
```

If it does not then check the styling and everything, because the above code would give you the exact tags as required.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers#:~:text=To%20accept%20an%20answer%3A,the%20answer%2C%20at%20any%20time.